# jQuery script conflicting

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a horizontally scrolling website using jQuery and I also want to add this hide and show function. However, after I insert another jQuery script for the hiding function, the easing effect for horizontally scrolling is not working! So that when I click the navigation of the site, it jumps to another section.

Here's my code of the jQuery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/jquery.localscroll-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x';
        $.localScroll();
    });
</script>
<!-----------------------hiding div------------------------------------>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

        $('.show_hide').click(function () {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: where is the second snippet located and when is it inserted ?

Comment: Check whether the scrolling and easing functions make use of the same version of Jquery. Do you see any javascript error? You can try debugging by pointing to the easing function to check if it actually gets called

Comment: Remember to put "return false;" just before closing the click callback to prevent default behaviour of show_hide if it's an anchor tag.

Comment: @ninty9notout no - `e.preventDefault()` is the correct way to do this... unless you want to prevent any other events that have been bound to the element from firing too.

Comment: What is the error, and where is your easing script stored? 

Console.log me the $.easing object

Comment: jQuery v1.3.2 was released 3 years ago, you should use an updated version, the current one is v1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering that you are using correct scripts as per your requirements.

Many JavaScript libraries use '$' as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, '$' is just an alias for 'jQuery'. To fix this add jquery in no conflict mode.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Include all your jquery code as below :

```
(function($) {    

     //jquery code goes here.    

})(jQuery);
```

See the complete code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //no conflict jquery
    jQuery.noConflict();

    (function ($) {

        //jquery code goes here.         
        $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x';
        $.localScroll();

    })(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

        $('.show_hide').click(function () {

            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```